# Jobeet for Symfony 2

Tags: php, frameworks, doctrine, symfony

I'm learning Symfony 2 with this tutorial from [here](http://sftuts.com/doc/jobeet/en/the-data-model.html). After loading the fixtures:
`php app/console doctrine:data:load`

I get this error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
Command  "doctrine:data:load" is not defined.
```

Official site symfony.com has nothing about MODEL.
Does anyone know any tutorials related to Jobeet?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the Doctrine fixtures bundle to be able to load data fixtures in Symfony2 (which is what `doctrine:data:load` is trying to do; there is a cookbook recipe found [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/doctrine_fixtures.html) (Symfony.com) that should get you started.

Comment: thanks for reply!

i dont use git, because i have windows. i downloaded Doctrine Data Fixtures and where i have to extract? why not have a description without a git?

Comment: git is available [for windows](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/), but the vendors script clones the repo into `vendor/doctrine-fixtures`, I believe.

Comment: So how can I install the Fixture package under windows? I tryed the way from here http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/doctrine_fixtures.html but I always get the message 

Your project seems to be based on a Standard Edition that includes vendors.

Try to run ./bin/vendors install --reinstall

If I do so it seams there is more broken afterwards than fixed.

Comment: @lony do you have the newest DEPS and DEPS.lock files from the symfony-standard project? If not, download them [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard.git), because the vendors file uses them to know what commit to use.

Comment: @Problematic I just downloaded the Symfony 2.0 zip and extracted it. How can I find out if it is the newest DEPS-file? Attachment:  [DEPS](http://pastebin.com/3qFhQqk8), [DEPS.lock](http://pastebin.com/G6XPWAdW) file (both like they are after extraction - no fixture entries)

Comment: SOLUTION!! I deleted the vendors folder and then installed again. Before that I deleted the .svn files inside all folders. Know it seams everything is installed.

Answer (score 3):

You can find a jobeet tutorial for symfony 2 here: [Symfony 2 Jobeet](http://www.ens.ro/2012/03/21/jobeet-with-symfony2/)

Answer (score 3):

Another fine tutorial for symfony 2.0 beginners

http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/

It covers many topics which can be very useful.

It is particularly very good for those who wants to get quick intro of Symfony 2.0 as they have used earlier versions of symfony.

Hope it will help someone.